# Upper Deck Corner Supports Rotting on Top

Tags: repair, wood, deck

I have a 12 foot high upper deck. I knew that the decking needed replacement, but when I started removing the far end deck boards, I noticed the corner support posts have started rotting at the very top. I don't believe the top few inches are load bearing and the remainder of the posts seem solid.

Hoping for advice on whether I can fill the ends with some type of epoxy or simply cut off the rotted part and seal the ends with something. (I've been told that the posts "wick" moisture up from the base to the top, so this is why the tops are rotting).

The pictures are looking up from the ground level and looking down from the deck level at the worst of the two corner support posts.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Lower view of the corner post]

[image: Top view of the corner post]

Comment: That looks like ant or termite damage.  I know they aren't supposed to like treated wood, but I have seen treated wood with damage like that before.

Comment: I thought it was termite damage, too. A termite guy came out and said it was just wood rot as the ends hold moisture. The texture of the rot is like sawdust and it's definitely very damp.

Am still wondering if the rot may be shallow enough to cut the top couple of inches off and sand/fill with a resin for outdoor wood.